# parent tag of tag 'img' is 'span', but it can only be 'i-amphtml-sizer-intrinsic'. error Custom JavaScript is not allowed

Tags: reactjs, next.js, amp-html

> error  The parent tag of tag 'img' is 'span', but it can only be 'i-amphtml-sizer-intrinsic'.
> error  Custom JavaScript is not allowed.                                                       https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/validation-workflow/validation_errors/#custom-javascript-is-not-allowed
>
> at async build (/home/vrch/Desktop/vrch-next/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:37:212)
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! vrch-next@1.0.0 export: `cross-env-shell NODE_ENV=isDev "next build && next export && node sitemap_generator.js"`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the vrch-next@1.0.0 export script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     home/vrch/.npm/_logs/2020-08-26T07_12_23_654Z-debug.log

Error showing while exporting react.js project with AMP pages

1. I have not used javascript in AMP
2. Even after commenting all AMP pages error is showing up!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

this error happened because amp page is not allowed html element inside the component, you should use amp tag itself. p